# Laravel storage path isn't accesisble. How to access it from url?

Tags: laravel

In a laravel I currently have a file saving to the storage directory.
The file appears here

```
"myroot/storage/app/public/attribute_item/3pCPNl7XaJpIsryhRuVYPdqNp4rKknU737mQ3bGz.svg"
```

I can visually confirm it's there.
I then attempt to load this up with the following url which is stored in my db:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/'. $item->image_path) }}" height="50" width="50" onClick="selectImage(this)" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
```

This gives me a 404 that it doesn't exist.  The request url it's attempting to get is this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/public/attribute_item/3pCPNl7XaJpIsryhRuVYPdqNp4rKknU737mQ3bGz.svg

What am I missing here?  Is there a specific way I have to call a storage asset?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Answer (score 1):

I was missing this part: `php artisan storage:link`
This creates the symlink so it will be viewable publicly.

More info found here:
[laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)